# Meteor how to use an array from mongodb collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, templates, meteor

Try to use a Mongodb collection that has an array . Want to use the array in the template. The

```
Index.html

<body>
{{>test}}
</body>
<template name="test">
{{ #each task}}
 <p>{{this}}</p>
 {{/each}}
 </template>

The app.js

Task= new Mongo.Collection("Tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.test.helpers({
    task: function () {
      return Tasks.find({"cat":"TASK"}, {"_id":0, "ALL_TASKS":1});
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer){

    if (Task.find({}).count() === 0){
      Task.insert({"cat":"TASK", "ALL_TASKS":["t1","t2"]})
    }

}
```

It does not work. What is that I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use one more `{{#each}}` . The `{{#each}}` that you are using is returning the collection object rather than the actual wanted array. Try this:

```
 <template name="test">
   {{#each task}}
       {{#each this.ALL_TASKS}}
         <p>{{this}}</p>
       {{/each
   {{/each}}
 </template>
```

Notice that `this.ALL_TASKS` is now looping through the array inside of the collection object.

Your helper would look like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
 // This code only runs on the client
  Template.test.helpers({
   task: function () {
    return Tasks.find({"cat":"TASK"});
   }
 });
}
```